# Limitations on where or when Beans are accessible

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I'm facing a situation where the Beans I've created are not accessible which makes me wonder where and when they are!?

I've made two Beans, one scoped `singleton` and other scoped `request`. I've made sure they are correctly implemented by autowiring them in a `RestController` class. And they are populated, no doubt there.

Now I have written an authorization checker class extending [`PreInvocationAuthorizationAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PreInvocationAuthorizationAdvice.html). Being an authorization class, I need to have access to current user's information. So I autowired current user's Bean to this class, this is the `request` scoped Bean. Also I need a customized ACL engine, which is autowired in a `singleton` manner. But when I reach the point when I need to use these two properties, they are both `null`!

So what are limitations on where and when I can expect a Bean to be accessible?

BTW, my `@Configuration` class is also annotated by `@ComponentScan({"my.base.package"})` which is a parent package of my designated class including the `@Autowired` property.

**[UPDATE]**

I think I found what the problem is, but yet I'm struggling with the solution.

The class with `@Autowired` properties, is being instantiated as Bean itself. I think this late Bean is getting instantiated before the other Beans which it is depending on and as the result they are not yet available. Is there anyway I can specify the ordering of the Beans being instantiated?

**[P.S.]**

Anyone who flagged this question as *"off-topic because: This question does not appear to be about programming"* is so funny :)

**[UPDATE]**

Just an example when `@Autowired` property is null.

These are my configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("/config.properties")
@ComponentScan({"my.package"})
public class AppConfig implements ApplicationContextAware
{
    private ApplicationContext appContext;
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        throws BeansException
    {
        this.appContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedissonClient getRedisson()
    {
        //Code ommited: returning a redisson connection.
    }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"my.pacakge"})
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public AclEngine getAclEngine()
    {
        return new AclEngine();
    }

    @Autowired
    private RedissonClient redisson;

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request")
    public User getCurrentUser()
    {
        //Code ommited: retrieving the user from Redisson and returning it.
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception
    {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticator());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticator()
    {
        return new AclAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository getHttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
    {
        HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository x = new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
        x.setAllowSessionCreation(false);
        return x;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityContextPersistenceFilter getSecurityContextPersistenceFilter()
    {
        return new SecurityContextPersistenceFilter(getHttpSessionSecurityContextRepository());
    }

    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager()
    {
        try {
            AffirmativeBased ab = (AffirmativeBased) super.accessDecisionManager();
            List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> advs = ab.getDecisionVoters();
            ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice = new ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice();

            List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
            for (AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object> adv : advs) {
                if (adv instanceof PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter) {
                    toBeRemoved.add(adv);
                }
            }
            for (AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object> adv : toBeRemoved) {
                advs.remove(adv);
            }
            advs.add(new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(expressionAdvice));
            return ab;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException ex) {
            ArrayList decisionVoters = new ArrayList();
            ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice = new ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
            decisionVoters.add(new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(expressionAdvice));
            return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
        }
    }

    public class AclAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider
    {
        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication)
        {
            return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
        }
    }

    public class SessionInitializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer
    {
        public SessionInitializer()
        {
            super(SecurityConfig.class);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally where I face the problem:

```
public class ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice implements PreInvocationAuthorizationAdvice
{
    @Autowired
    private User currentUser;
    @Autowired
    private AclEngine aclEngine;

    @Override
    public boolean before(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation methodInvocation, PreInvocationAttribute preInvocationAttribute)
    {
        //Where I want to access currentUser and aclEngine but they are null.
        //I can trace the code to this point without any Exception thrown!
    }
}
```

Comment: Might you be able to share some code example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: If you have used `@Autowired` they cannot be null, if they would be null you would get an exception. Show the configuration that you are using. Also when using Spring Boot you can simply do `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` to get the current user.

Comment: @M.Deinum They can be null, it's just matter of time. At some point they are null before they are not. I think I'm accessing them before they get instantiated. I've updated the stem.

Comment: @Mehran the specific reason for voting to close is "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. " And I agree with this assessment

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd What if the problem is so vogue that finding the root of it is a problem itself? I think that's my case here. Right now here, the problem is not within my code. It's just that Spring framework didn't bother to check for Bean dependencies, or at least they didn't bother to mention the possibility of facing the problem in their documentation. What other choice do I have but to present my problem hoping someone has faced them same before?

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd My case might be like `why my code is not working` but that's not my question. In my opinion, my question is totally programming related!

Comment: No they cannot be null... The auto wiring support checks for that, if it cannot satisfy a dependency it will throw an exception while starting up which stops the bootstrapping of your application. Hence the request for your actual configuration instead of a description of your configuration which you expect to work.

Comment: @M.Deinum You know that `@Autowire` work through reflection, right? Which means there's a code somewhere within Spring that will populate them. If you manage to run your code before that, then they will be null.

Comment: Trust me I know how spring works having written to books and as a regular contributor. But if you want to question my knowledge on Spring be my guest. You seem to not want to improve your question and add the requested information, so I'm backing of this question. If your bean is constructed as you say it is the dependencies cannot be null as that violaties how the auto wiring in Spring works, the rule is simple if a dependency cannot be satisfied your application will blow up.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry I didn't mean to offend you. It's just that my knowledge regarding the inner workings of Spring is limited and I try to tackle the problem from a logical angle. I'll update the question with some code, yet I stand my ground that autowired properties can be null, as I can see they are.

Comment: If they are `null` then you aren't using auto wiring for that bean and the instance you are using isn't a spring managed bean. If it would have been startup of your application will fail. There is nowhere in your configuration that your custom class is defined as a bean, hence no spring managed bean and no auto wiring. I suspect (but you left that code out) that you do a `new YourBean` inside the method, which basically means you have an arbitrary instance of that class which isn't managed by spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not sure if I follow! It's been a while since I've studied Spring's Beans, if I remember correctly for auto wiring to work these are the necessary ingredients: **1)** A class annotated by `@Configuration` **2)** A method within that class annotated by `@Bean` returning an object of some desired type **3)** Some property of that type annotated by `@Autowired` defined a class within a package named in class *1)* as `@ComponentScan({"my.package"})`. I omitted `new Bean` parts of my code because I have those exact two autowired in some other class instantiated and working. Thank you.

Comment: You don't have a method annotated with `@Bean` returning anything resembling `ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice`. Which makes it an arbitrary object not a spring managed object and as hence will not receive any auto wiring... It doesn't do injection in beans it doesn't know. But as mentioned you are leaving out the part that is constructing the instance of `ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice` basically making your question still incomplete for some reason you don't want to give all information needed and follow through on misunderstandings on how spring auto wiring works.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry I misunderstood you! I've got no problem giving all the information. I just didn't want to make things too complicated, I didn't think that part was important. I'll update the question and code right away.

Comment: And I'm going to tell you for the last time that your instance of `ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice` isn't a spring managed bean. You are creating an instance inside that method (as I mentioned before). That instance is invisible to spring and will never be processed and will never get auto wired.As I explained before spring will only inject beans into spring managed instances. In short create a `@Bean` method for the `ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice` instead of creating a new instance inside that method.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for. Could you please post it so I can flag it as the answer? And I've never read your book or anything but this small point you've just mentioned is really important and I've never had heard about it before!

Comment: @M.Deinum BTW, now I've got other issues which I'm not gonna dilute this problem with. At least now they are not `null` anymore, instead they are gibberish!! Maybe I'll post it as another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager()
{
    try {
        AffirmativeBased ab = (AffirmativeBased) super.accessDecisionManager();
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> advs = ab.getDecisionVoters();
        ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice = new ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice();

        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
        for (AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object> adv : advs) {
            if (adv instanceof PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter) {
                toBeRemoved.add(adv);
            }
        }
        for (AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object> adv : toBeRemoved) {
            advs.remove(adv);
        }
        advs.add(new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(expressionAdvice));
        return ab;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException ex) {
        ArrayList decisionVoters = new ArrayList();
        ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice = new ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
        decisionVoters.add(new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(expressionAdvice));
        return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
    }
}
```

Spring will only inject references into class instances (aka beans) that it manages. When you are creating beans inside methods and directly inject them into other beans, those newly created beans are Spring Managed beans and as such aren't eligible for any auto wiring or post processing by spring whatsoever.

Instead of

```
ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice = new ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
```

You should move that code to a `@Bean` method so that is becomes a Spring managed bean and will be injected with the dependencies.

```
@Bean
public ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice() {
    return new ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
}
```

And just reference this method instead of creating a new instance.

```
ResourceBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice = expressionAdvice();
```